# Swapping the series and product in the zeta function euler product equality

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

I was thinking that we have a well known function satisfying the following relation:

$$ \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} h_n(x) =\prod_{\text{p prime}} j_p(x) $$

which is of course the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s).$ This function is expressible as a product of primes.

I wondered if there could exist a reverse sort of function:

$$ \sum_{\text{p}~\text{prime}}f_p(x)=\prod_{n\in \Bbb N} g_n(x) $$

where we need the sum over primes equal to some product function.

> Does a function like this exist? How would you construct it?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but, ... the traditional use of the Euler product is to take logarithms (and/or logarithmic derivatives) to have a _sum_ over primes instead of a product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given **any** two function $\;h_n(x)\;$ and $\;j_p(x)\;$ with $p$ prime
and where
$$ \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} h_n(x) =\prod_{p\text{ prime}} j_p(x), \tag1 $$
then define another two functions $\;f_p(x)\;$ and $\;g_n(x)\;$ with
$$ h_n(x) :=f_{p_n}(x),\quad \text{and} \quad g_n(x) :=j_{p_n}(x) \tag2 $$ where $\;p_n\;$ is the $n$-th prime. Then
$$ \sum_{p\text{ prime}}f_p(x) = 
   \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} h_n(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad
  \prod_{n\in\Bbb N} g_n(x) =\prod_{p\text{ prime}}j_p(x). \tag3 $$

Thus, equation $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{p\text{ prime}}f_p(x)=\prod_{n\in \Bbb N} g_n(x) \tag4 $$
because they both equate the same sum to the same product.

---

The standard example of equation $(1)$ is the Riemann $\;\zeta\;$ function:
$$ \zeta(x) = \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} n^{-x} = \prod_{p\text{ prime}}
 \frac1{1-p^{-x}}, \tag5 $$
where $\;h_n(x) = n^{-x}\;$ and $\;j_p(x) = (1-p^{-x})^{-1}.\;$
Define the inverse function whose domain is all primes by
$\; q(p_n) := n.\;$ The equivalent to equation $(5)$ is
$$ \zeta(x) = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} q(p)^{-x} = \prod_{n\in \Bbb N}
 \frac1{1-p_n^{-x}}. \tag6 $$

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that works?

Comment: @geocalc33 Give me an example of $h_n(x)$ and $j_p(x)$.

Comment: I don't have any examples because I couldn't find a natural one